# ADXL345 shows acceleration rating when stationary

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, accelerometer

I am using an ADXL345 accelerometer connected to a Raspberry Pi 3B+.I have written a python code to check the acceleration value. However, the accelerometer always shows a non-zero value for the x and y axes and a constant value for the z-axis even when stationary. Doesn't seem to be an error of the code as I have taken it from the documentation. I am a beginner so any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a question for https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okay thanks I'll put it up over there

Answer (score 0):

The output of adxl345 will vary according to the stance of your sensor board, so it is normal to have non-zero values. You can follow [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adxl345-digital-accelerometer/programming) to conduct the callibration.